# Installing pandas: UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, linux, pandas, installation, server

I have some problem while installing pandas on Linux Server 
I'm trying to install it, it creates it own `venv`, my requirement files looks like this:

```
Flask==0.10.1
pandas==0.16.2
```

Locally it is installed correctly but only on the server, I can't do it for some reasons that I can't understand.

I tried t find a solution but I don't get what could be the problem? Please help me!

My errors looks like this

[image]

So:

```
Command /var/www/jsonify-it/venv/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/www/jsonify-it/venv/build/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-B_NcK3-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /var/www/jsonify-it/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /var/www/jsonify-it/venv/build/pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/jsonify-it/venv/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.4.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/var/www/jsonify-it/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 148, in main
    return command.main(args[1:], options)
  File "/var/www/jsonify-it/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 169, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 72: ordinal not in range(128)
Installation complete.
```

I don't get what could be the problem? Please help!

UPDATE: 
Solution:

Finally, I found my problem:
I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

Then the solution (if you have no ability to increase memory on that machine) is to add swap file.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1024 count=524288
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Answer (score 2):

new version of pip solve the problem. Update pip will solve problem. 
pip install --upgrade pip